# How to convert the string value of a dictionary into boolean values?

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean, key-value-store

I have created a dictionary containing keys and values. After reading a text file like this:

```
test1
    House: True
    Car: False
    Money: False
    Case: 1

test2
    House: True
    Car: False
    Money: False
    Case: 2

test3
    House: True
    Car: False
    Money: False
    Case: 3
```

the dictionary is created. The problem is that the values are read as strings. I need to have them as bools so that later I can parse them to a JSON file and use them there as bools. The dictionary created is called `answer`. I tried the following but it is only giving me `True` as boolean:

```
    to_json = {}
    block_cnt = 1
    header = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]')
    inner = re.compile("[\t]")
    empty = re.compile("[\n]",)`

    with open(rDEMO_parameters.txt', 'r') as document:
    for line in document:
        #print line
        if empty.match(line[0]):
            continue

        elif header.match(line[0]):
            if answer:
                to_json[block_cnt] = answer
                #print answer
                block_cnt += 1
                answer = {}
        elif inner.match(line[0]):
            _key, value = line.split(":  ")
            tab, key = _key.split("\t")
            answer[key] = value.split()
           for key in answer.keys():
            if key == "House":
                answer[key] = map(bool, answer[key])
            if key == "Car":
                answer[key] = map(bool, answer[key])
            if key == "Money":
                answer[key] = map(bool, answer[key])
            if key == "Case":
                answer[key] = map(int, answer[key])


   f = open(r"parameters.json", "w")

   json.dump(to_json, f)
   f.close()
```

Then after converting I only get something like this but everything in only one line:

```
 {1
   {
    House: True
    Car: True
    Money: True
    Case: [1]
             } }
 {2
   {
    House: True
    Car: True
    Money: True
    Case: [2] } }
 {3
    {
    House: True
    Car: True
    Money: True
    Case: [3] }}
```

So the strings are all converted to `True` booleans, which is not the case.
The other problem is that the values are read inside lists. Is there any method to avoid that? Thank you.

Comment: Please show the code that parses the file

Comment: Does the key have a trailing space, eg `'House '` rather than `'House'`?

Comment: `map` will apply `bool` to each character in the value, e.g. `'False'` will give `[True, True, True, True, True]` as `bool('F') == True`, `bool('a') == True`, `bool('l') == True`, etc.

Comment: show the code that parses the file +1, so that we can get exact look at your answer dict.

Comment: @PeterWood I put the full Code, Input and Output. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` is used to apply a function to each value in an iterable.

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead:

```
from ast import literal_eval

answer[key] = literal_eval(answer[key])
```

Moreover, you don't need to check for each key in a separate `if` statement. It's also more idiomatic to iterate over `dict.items` if you are using both key and value in your logic:

```
for key, value in answer.items():
    if key in ('House', 'Car', 'Money'):
        answer[key] = literal_eval(value)
```

Finally, consider using a dictionary comprehension instead:

```
# for modifying over all values
answer = {k: literal_eval(v) for k, v in answer.items()}

# for modifying selected values
select = {'House', 'Car', 'Money'}
answer = {k: literal_eval(v) if k in select else v for k, v in answer.items()}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Still i am getting the following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\s - Kopie.py", line 49, in <module>
    answer[key] = literal_eval(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string

Comment: I can't reproduce. Looks like one of your strings are **not** `"True"` or `"False"`. This is not reflected in your original question.

Comment: The values are inside lists. For example: House: ['True']  Car: ['False'] etc. Can that be the reason?

Comment: @Dj_96, Yes, that's probably the reason. If those are lists you need to use `value[0]` or `v[0]` in my solutions to get the first item.

Comment: i tried it and the error above is gone. However i get another error:        answer[key] = literal_eval(value[0])
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @Dj_96, So looks like your data is inconsistent. Some are `True`, some are `['True']`, maybe some are even `"True"`. For me to help further, you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52610400/9209546) with a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, i added the complete Code, Input and output, hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

`map(bool, answer[key])` is mapping the function over the characters of a string. All non empty characters are true, so you should expect to only get True.

You need to actually check for `== "True"`

In other words, result of `bool("False")` might surprise you

Comment: I don't think this is the reason, otherwise OP would get a `list` of `bool`. I don't think it's applying the conversion at all, as the keys have spaces in them.

Comment: `map()` should return a list or generator yes, but that isn't what OP is seeing, so I went with the minimal information that was given in the question. Still, using map at all is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your bools are strings and you need them to actually be bools, if so *dictionary comprehension* will work

```
d = {k: True if d[k] == 'True' else False for k in d}
```

> ```
>  {'House': True, 'Car': False, 'Money': False}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
for key in answer.keys():
   answer[key] = answer[key] == "True"
```

Comment: Or just `for key in answer:`

Comment: Hi, now it prints everything false